# Web scraping - get tag through text in "brother" tag - beautiful soup

Tags: beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I'm trying to get the text inside a table in wikipedia, but I will do it for many cases (books in this case). I want to get the book genres.

[Html code for the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnb6z.png)

I need to extract the td containing the genre, when the text in  Genre.

I did this:

````
page2 = urllib.request.urlopen(url2)

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2, 'html.parser')
for table in soup2.find_all('table', class_='infobox vcard'):
    for tr in table.findAll('tr')[5:6]:
        for td in tr.findAll('td'):
            print(td.getText(separator="\n"))```

This gets me the genre but only in some pages due to the row count which differs. 

Example of page where this does not work 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Catcher_in_the_Rye (table on the right side)

Anyone knows how to search through string with "genre"? Thank you
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, you don't need to bother with all that. Just try:

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Catcher_in_the_Rye')
print(tables[0])
```

Output:

```
                     0                                       1
0   First edition cover                     First edition cover
1                Author                          J. D. Salinger
2          Cover artist               E. Michael Mitchell[1][2]
3               Country                           United States
4              Language                                 English
5                 Genre  Realistic fictionComing-of-age fiction
6             Published                           July 16, 1951
7             Publisher               Little, Brown and Company
8            Media type                                   Print
9                 Pages                          234 (may vary)
10                 OCLC                                  287628
11        Dewey Decimal                                  813.54
```

From here you can use standard pandas methods to extract whatever you need.